# CakePHP 1.3.7 inverse routing returning default url, instead of the configured one

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, html-helper

Im developing a simple application with CakePHP v1.3.7 Stable. I want to generate a simple user profile page, accessible by the url: **my.domain/u/id**, where **id** is the id of the user in database.

So i wrote this (and only this) in app/config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/u/:id',
    array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile') 
        ,array('pass'=>array('id'),'id'=>'[0-9]+')
);
```

The above code works fine, when i put **my.domain/u/120** in the browser, it shows the profile of user 120.

But, when i try to create a link to this page using the Html helper:

```
// some code in a view
$this->html->link('Test', array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'profile', 120))
```

The html helper (doing inverse routing, i think) generates the url in the defaut cakephp form: `<a href="/users/profile/120">Test</a>`

Based on the configuration in routes.php, *it should be:* `<a href="/u/120">Test</a>`, right?

I'm missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: also you should be doing 'controller' => 'users' lower-case. read about cakes conventions,

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$this->html->link('Test', array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'profile', 'id'=>120))
```

I hope the missed 'id' will fix it.

Comment: if you dont want the 'id' => $id in the url change the route to Router::connect('/u/*'....

Comment: nope, if I include the 'id'=>$id, it renders: `<a href="/users/profile/id:1">Test</a>`, wich is even far from the `/u/id` i want, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to dogmatic69, I deleted the id related code of the route.

I end with this in routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/u/*',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile')
);
```

Now, the html helper works just as expected:

```
echo $this->html->link('Test',array(
    'controller'=>'users',
    'action'=>'profile', 
    100
))

// renders: <a href="/u/100">Test</a>
```

The drawback is that I can't take advantage of the regexp filter of the router, as in the initial route code.